# How can I make a wrap_content TextView stay to the left of a Button on ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-constraintlayout

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.constraintsample.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button with some text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it ends up looking like this:

[image]

But I want the text to stay to the left of the button while continuing to use `wrap_content`. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is fine, Just set `android:layout_width="0dp"` to your textView